# How to read and parse data from (Contec) Pulse Oximeter using evothing?

Tags: cordova

I want to develop a mobile app for connecting reading and parsing measurement data from Contec Pulse Oximeter by bluetooth using evothings (or phonegap)
I can connect, discover and read static data (device name, address ...), but I can not read measurement results. 
What service and characteristic should I use? Should I write descriptor to get measurement results?

Discover result is (evothings):

```
[
    {
        "type":0,"uuid":"00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
        "handle":1,
        "characteristics":[
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":4,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":5,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":6,
                "descriptors":[]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "type":0,"uuid":"0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
        "handle":2,
        "characteristics":[
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":7,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":8,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":9,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":10,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":11,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":12,"descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":13,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":2,
                "uuid":"00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                "handle":14,
                "descriptors":[]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "type":0,
        "uuid":"49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455",
        "handle":3,
        "characteristics":[
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":10,
                "uuid":"49535343-6daa-4d02-abf6-19569aca69fe",
                "handle":15,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":24,
                "uuid":"49535343-aca3-481c-91ec-d85e28a60318",
                "handle":16,
                "descriptors":[
                    {
                        "permissions":0,
                        "uuid":"00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "handle":20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":1,
                "properties":30,
                "uuid":"49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616",
                "handle":17,
                "descriptors":[
                    {
                        "permissions":0,
                        "uuid":"00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "handle":21
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":1,
                "properties":12,
                "uuid":"49535343-8841-43f4-a8d4-ecbe34729bb3",
                "handle":18,
                "descriptors":[]
            },
            {
                "permissions":0,
                "writeType":2,
                "properties":24,
                "uuid":"49535343-026e-3a9b-954c-97daef17e26e",
                "handle":19,
                "descriptors":[
                    {
                        "permissions":0,
                        "uuid":"00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "handle":22
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Phonegap (BLE plugin)

```
{
    "address":"8C:DE:52:80:B5:24",
    "status":"discovered",
    "services":[
        {"characteristics":
            [
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a00","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a01","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a04","properties":{"read":true}}
            ],
            "serviceUuid":"1800"
        },
        {"characteristics":
            [
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a29","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a24","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a25","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a27","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a26","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a28","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a23","properties":{"read":true}},
                {"descriptors":[],"characteristicUuid":"2a2a","properties":{"read":true}}
            ],
            "serviceUuid":"180a"
        },
        {"characteristics":
            [
                {
                    "descriptors":[],
                    "characteristicUuid":"49535343-6daa-4d02-abf6-19569aca69fe",
                    "properties":{"write":true,"read":true}
                },

                {
                    "descriptors":[{"descriptorUuid":"2902"}],
                    "characteristicUuid":"49535343-aca3-481c-91ec-d85e28a60318",
                    "properties":{"write":true,"notify":true}
                },

                {
                    "descriptors":[{"descriptorUuid":"2902"}],
                    "characteristicUuid":"49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616",
                    "properties":{"write":true,"writeWithoutResponse":true,"read":true,"notify":true}
                },

                {
                    "descriptors":[],
                    "characteristicUuid":"49535343-8841-43f4-a8d4-ecbe34729bb3",
                    "properties":{"write":true,"writeWithoutResponse":true}
                },

                {
                    "descriptors":[{"descriptorUuid":"2902"}],
                    "characteristicUuid":"49535343-026e-3a9b-954c-97daef17e26e",
                    "properties":{"write":true,"notify":true}
                }
            ],
            "serviceUuid":"49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455"
        }
    ],
    "name":"SpO2081127"
}
```

My JS code

```
// JavaScript code for the BLE Discovery example app.

// TODO: Add comments to functions, shorten long lines.

$(document).ready( function()
{

});

/** BLE plugin, is loaded asynchronously so the
    variable is redefined in the onDeviceReady handler. */
var ble = null;

// Application object.
var app = {};

// BLE device scanning will be made with this interval in milliseconds.
app.scanInterval = 5000;

// Track whether scanning is ongoing to avoid multiple intervals.
app.isScanning = false;

// Time for last scan event. This is useful for
// when the device does not support continuous scan.
app.lastScanEvent = 0;

// Application Constructor
app.initialize = function()
{
    this.bindEvents();
};

// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
app.bindEvents = function()
{
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
};

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
app.onDeviceReady = function()
{
    // The plugin was loaded asynchronously and can here be referenced.
    ble = evothings.ble;
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
};

app.receivedEvent = function(id)
{
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
};

app.scan = function(){
    ble.stopScan();
    $('#result').html('<span class="message">BLE device is scanning...</span>');
    ble.startScan(function(r){
        //$('#result').html('<span class="success">'+JSON.stringify(r)+'</span>');
        $('#result').html('<div class="device"><span class="message">'+r.name+'</span> [<span class="address">'+r.address+'</span>] <span class="success">'+r.rssi+'</span></div>');
        $('#result').append('<span class="message">Connecting...</span>');
        app.connect(r.address);
    }, function(){
        $('#result').html('<span class="error">BLE device scanning failed.</span>');
    });
}

app.connect = function(address) {
    ble.stopScan();
    //$('#result').append('<span class="success">'+address+'</span>');
    ble.connect(address, function(r){
        // state=2  deviceHandle=1
        $('#result').html('<span class="success">Successfully connected<br>'+JSON.stringify(r)+'</span>');
        app.services(r.deviceHandle);
    }, function(errorCode){
        $('#result').html('<span class="error">Connection failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
    });
};

app.services = function(deviceHandle){
    ble.readAllServiceData(deviceHandle, function(services){
        //$('#result').html('<span class="success">'+JSON.stringify(services)+'</span>');
        app.read(deviceHandle);
    }, function(errorCode){
        $('#result').html('<span class="error">Read services failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
    });
}

app.read = function(deviceHandle){
    /*
    ble.readCharacteristic(deviceHandle, 15, function(data){ 
        $('#result').html('<span class="success">['+ble.fromUtf8(data)+']</span>');
    }, function(errorCode){
        $('#result').html('<span class="error">Read failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
    });
    */


    ble.enableNotification(deviceHandle, 19, function(data){
        $('#result').html('<span class="success">['+ble.fromUtf8(data)+']<br>'+data+'</span>');
    }, function(errorCode){
        $('#result').html('<span class="error">Enable notification failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
    });


    ble.descriptors(deviceHandle,19, function(descriptors){
        $('#result').html('<span class="success">['+descriptors[0].handle+']</span>');
        ble.writeDescriptor(deviceHandle, descriptors[0].handle, new Uint8Array([1,0]), function(){
            $('#result').html('<span class="message">Write success.</span>');
        }, function(errorCode){
            $('#result').html('<span class="error">Write failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            ble.readDescriptor(deviceHandle, descriptors[0].handle, function(data){
                $('#result').html('<span class="success">['+ble.fromUtf8(data)+']<br>'+data+'</span>');
            }, function(errorCode){
                $('#result').html('<span class="error">Read descriptor failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
            })
        }, 10000);
    }, function(errorCode){
        $('#result').html('<span class="error">Characteristics failed ['+errorCode+'].</span>');
    });

}

$(document).on('click','#scan',app.scan);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contec oximeter indeed uses the [ISSC transparent service](https://github.com/ISSC/Bluebit/wiki/Transparent). That is service is not really oximeter specific, it is just a service to 'transparently' expose a serial connection over Bluetooth LE.

You only need to use 2 characteristics: the TX and the RX ones:

TX: 49535343-1E4D-4BD9-BA61-23C647249616

RX: 49535343-8841-43F4-A8D4-ECBE34729BB3

What you need to do is the following:

1. Turn notify on for the TX characteristic
2. Write commands to the RX characteristic (WriteWithResponse)
3. You will receive data on the TX characteristic

So for example, to turn realtime data streaming on:

1. Write the following 9 bytes to RX characteristic : {0x7D, 0x81, 0xA1, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80}. All commands are 9 bytes.
2. You will start receiving data on the TX characteristic at 60 Hz.

See [Albert Braun's Github project for the CMS50FW](https://github.com/albertcbraun/CMS50FW) for more commands and information about how to parse the data. That project also contains a [PDF with the documentation of the protocol](https://github.com/albertcbraun/CMS50FW/blob/master/Communication%20protocol%20of%20pulse%20oximeter%20V7.0.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You must not hard-code `characteristic.handles`, as you've done in your `app.read` function when calling `ble.enableNotification` and `ble.descriptors`. Those values are likely to change between runs of your program, and even more likely to change between platforms.

Instead, you will have to, in your `ble.readAllServiceData` callback, iterate through services and their characteristics, look for a characteristic with the UUID you want, save its handle (usually in an `app.member`), and use it in `app.read`.

To simplify this (rather common) task in BLE programming, we have a library called "[easyble](https://github.com/evothings/evothings-examples/tree/master/resources/libs/evothings/easyble)", built on top of the BLE plugin. Use it if you want.

Comment: it does not help too. readDescriptor returns the string that i wrote using writeDescritor. May be, i should use writeCharacteristic Or write special sting  (as key, some command ..) into descriptor?

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. Descriptors are read-write buffers; they will always return (on read) what you wrote into them.

Comment: I have enabled notifications and then writeDescriptor to start notifications. But i do not get any notification, so i use the readDescriptor operation. readDescriptor returns the value, that i have wrote before (using writeDescriptor). Must not it return the measurement result?

Comment: No, descriptors are intended for control and metadata of characteristics. It is the **characteristic** that contains the measurement data.

Comment: What can i do, if notifications not responding? My be, i must write special command into descriptors?

Comment: Yes, Uint8Array([1,0]) to the "2902" descriptor tells the remote device to start sending notifications **when it feels like it**. If the characteristic's value does not change, then no notifications will be sent. I have also heard of bugs in some devices that cause notifications to stop when you call readCharacteristic, so if I were you I'd be careful to try one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: The same result (( 
May be, i must write some special command for this device?
Using 'easyble' does not help, also.
There is my full code. Can you check it, please
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B18I7eXdy0kWVVJBcU4wakpuTlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I started investigating, and found so many things that I had to write a new answer post.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious fault I could find with your linked example is that you don't check the descriptors' UUID (which is bad because there could be other descriptors than the "2902" ones), but if the discover result you posted earlier holds constant, then that shouldn't stop this particular program from working.

I remember now that some devices require you to write certain values to certain characteristics in order to start measurements that will result in notifications. For example, the Texas Instruments [SensorTag](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide) (link).

A Google search on your service UUID indicates that it is called "[ISSC Proprietary Service](https://github.com/ISSC/Bluebit/wiki/Transparent)", and appears to act as some sort of serial data-link. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation in English.

If this service is used to run a Heart Rate Monitor, then I suspect that your problem just got a lot more complicated.

At this point I remembered that I'd been stupid and not looked up the name of the device you were using. The Contec Pulse Oximeter, as originally constructed, appears to use [a rather complex serial protocol](https://github.com/YourBrain/Contec-Pulse-Oximeter-in-Matlab/raw/master/Communication%20protocol%20of%20pulse%20oximeter%20V7.0.pdf) designed to work over RS232 or USB connections. This explains the ISSC serial service. Unfortunately, it doesn't help us very much, because we still don't know how that service works.

I also cannot find any mention on the Internet of any Contec device that uses BLE. Do you have a user manual, or any documentation that describes your device's communication protocol?

Comment: Discover result returns only 2902 descriptor for characteristics. I found this pdf https://github.com/YourBrain/Contec-Pulse-Oximeter-in-Matlab/blob/master/Communication%20protocol%20of%20pulse%20oximeter%20V7.0.pdf  (the same with that what you found )but i do not know how to use it. And there are https://github.com/YourBrain/Contec-Pulse-Oximeter-in-Matlab/blob/master/HeartRateUSB.m shown some commands. May be i nedd one of them? 
May be, you can help me to choose other manufacturers' devices, where such problems will not appear

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/BM77_PICtail_User_Guide_Draft.pdf i found it today. May be, we can find there something useful

Comment: i also found this example https://www.tranzoa.net/~alex/blog/images/Communication%20protocol.pdf and https://github.com/atbrask/CMS50Dplus

Comment: All the links you posted talk about the USB version of the Oximeter, not the Bluetooth version you have. The python code indicates that the device should be sending live data automatically, as soon as you connect. I suspect you have to do something with this ISSC serial-over-GATT thing to get it to work... Found something in the Bluebit code. This will require another answer post.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluebit class ActivityTransparent indicates that activating notifications on the TX characteristic (UUID 49535343-1e4d-4bd9-ba61-23c647249616) should get it to start sending data. You could try doing **only** that characteristic and none of the others.

Comment: https://github.com/ISSC/Bluebit/blob/master/src/com/issc/gatt/GattDescriptor.java there  i found this value ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE = 0x5987, but i do not know how can i use it (in which form to write this value into descriptor)

Comment: I found that too, but it's used only as an internal identifier in the Bluebit library; it is never sent to the device. Ignore it.

Comment: I suspect that, i must enable notifications of UUID=...9616 characteristic (and write into descriptor new uint8array([1,0])) and write command into uuid=...bb3 charcteristic to send to device some commands. May be?
http://www.aiuxian.com/article/p-2505464.html

Comment: I tested this app only on android os. Is it possible that, it will work correctly on ios?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "this app", but if you use JavaScript with the Evothings app, it should work on both platforms. The Bluebit library and the aiuxian example, being native Android Java code, will of course not work on iOS.

Comment: Do you know in what form should i write hex code into descriptor (or characteristic). For example 0xA1. Must i convert it to decimal then uint8array?

Comment: Conversion is not required. Uint8Arrays take JavaScript Arrays of Numbers, and those numbers may be decimal, octal or hex. You can even mix them, like so: `new Uint8Array([5, 073, 0xFF])`